# what $h_a$ in this triangle question.

Tags: geometry, notation, triangles, quadrilateral

> Square $PQRS$ is inscribed into $\triangle ABC$ so that vertices $P$ and $Q$ lie on sides $AB$ and $AC$ and vertices $R$ and $S$ lie on $BC$. Express the length of the square’s side through $a$ and $h_a$.

What is $h_a$?

Comment: I don't know...:) Is there more information? figures? Perhaps, the triangle $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle with edge length $a$ and its height is $h_a$?

Comment: @mathlove No there isn't any other information.-[source](http://students.imsa.edu/~tliu/Math/planegeo.pdf)

Comment: OK. please tell me the page of the question. so many pages...

Comment: @mathlove page # - 15...

Comment: Thanks. I agree with Stefan4024, but as you said, I can't find any other information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually with $h$ we note the height of the triangle. So with $h_a$ we note the height that perpendicular to the side $a$. Usually with $a$ we note the side opposite of the vertex $A$ , i.e. the side $BC$.

But as I said it's usual math notation, but that doesn't mean it's right for you problem.

Comment: Is the $a$ mentioned in the question length of side of square or the length of side opposite to vertex $A$?

Comment: Maybe the [source](http://students.imsa.edu/~tliu/Math/planegeo.pdf) of the question can tell something.

Comment: $a$ is the side of the traingle because, the question says: "Express the length of the square’s side through a..."